# Problem with creating and adding data into a text file in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I have created the following procedure that using two different prepared statements, writes some data in a text file with the same name.

**PROCEDURE**

```
delimiter !!
drop procedure if exists copyIntoFile !!
create procedure copyIntoFile()

begin
    declare path varchar(255);
    set path = concat("'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/", curdate(), ".txt'");

    set @aux1 = concat("select * from movie_modification where modified = true into outfile ", path, 
                        " fields terminated by ';' lines starting by 'Edit: ' terminated by '\n';");
    prepare stmt1 from @aux1;
    execute stmt1;
    deallocate prepare stmt1;

    set @aux2 = concat("select * from movie_modification where modified = false into outfile ", path, 
                        " fields terminated by ';' lines starting by 'New: ' terminated by '\n';");
    prepare stmt2 from @aux2;
    execute stmt2;
    deallocate prepare stmt2;

    delete from movie_modification;
end !!
delimiter ;
```

When I executed this procedure, statement `aux1` executes correctly and creates the text file and writes the data in it. But when the execution goes to the second statement (`aux2`), I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1086. File 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/2020-04-03.txt' already exists

This error occurs because the file is already being created in statement `aux1`.

How can I modify then the second statement `aux2` knowing the file it's already been created?

Comment: How do you want to modify the second statement - do you want to create a different file or append to the existing file?

Comment: I want to append to the existing file

Comment: `TRUNCATE TABLE movie_modification;` is probably the fastest way to remove all rows from the table. It's a big, and effective, hammer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I  dont think you can ask MySQL to append to the same file, but you could UNION the 2 queries.

You can add the `'Edit: '` and `'New: '` into the query, therefore allowing you to use a UNION to reduce this to one query.

You may have to change your query to specify all the columns you want a `SELECT 'Edit: ',*` wont work, but here is a suggestion.

```
delimiter !!
drop procedure if exists copyIntoFile !!
create procedure copyIntoFile()

begin
    declare path varchar(255);
    set path = concat("'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/", curdate(), ".txt'");

    set @aux = concat("select 'Edit: ', col1,col2 from movie_modification where modified = true
                    UNION ALL
                    select 'New: ', col1,col2 from movie_modification where modified = false
                 into outfile ", path, 
                 " fields terminated by ';' lines terminated by '\n';");

    prepare stmt from @aux;
    execute stmt;

    deallocate prepare stmt;
    delete from movie_modification;
end !!
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Not sure what '' lines starting by 'New: '' does in an outfile but second query is slightly different to first in this regard Perhaps a simple string(s) in the select would suffice.

Comment: @P.Salmon Ooo I didnt spot that, thanks, will have to think again on this one

Comment: think I have a solution, sorry took so long, got called away

Comment: I think you must use UNION ALL.

Comment: @Akina Ok, but I dont see any duplicates, but there may well be. Thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly Even when no duplicated UNION causes the server  to perform excess sorting.

Comment: Ok, will remember that

Comment: `UNION ALL` is a little faster because it doesn't have to dedup. But modern query planners can tell when unique indexes or primary keys make duplicates impossible, which which case `UNION` is just as fast.

Comment: @O.Jones IN shown case two different string literals are applied... I doubt that query planner will detect that the UNION of 2 joined non-unique expressions is unique.